# How do i search 'titles' from array of objects & return only objects that match searchTerm?

Tags: javascript, jquery

bit of a newbie! I am trying to re-populate a carousel of images... based on an array of search results. But really hitting surprising amount of issues.

I'm using JS/Jquery and have, say, an array of objects that exist from my api:

```
let arrayOfObjects = [ 
{id: 0, title: 'Beauty & The Beast', img: 'https://imgthing1.com' }, 
{id: 1, title: 'The Brainiac', img: 'https://imgthing2.com' }, 
{id: 2, title: 'Mac and Me', img: 'https://imgthing3.com' }
];
```

Then i have my searchTerm which i want to filter the array down, and return a new array of results from:-

```
function checkWords(searchTerm, arr) {
    let results = [];
    let st = searchTerm.toLowerCase();

// **** i map through the array - if the search term (say its 'a' is the same
// as the first character of an object's 'title'... then it stores
// that object in results, ready to be rendered. ****

    arr.map((each) => {
      if (st === each.title.charAt(0)) {
         results.push(each)
      }
    })

    console.log(finalResults);

}
```

But i can't work out how to keep it matching... based on:
'Bea' vs 'Beauty & The Beast' - pass.
'Beat' vs 'Beauty & The Beast' - fail.

Comment: Instead of `map` use `filter`.

Comment: `charAt` will only look at .... one char.

Comment: you need to use `each.title.indexOf(st) > -1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and check if the string contains the wanted string at position zero.

```js
let arrayOfObjects = [{ id: 0, title: 'Beauty & The Beast', img: 'https://imgthing1.com' }, { id: 1, title: 'The Brainiac', img: 'https://imgthing2.com' }, { id: 2, title: 'Mac and Me', img: 'https://imgthing3.com' }];


function checkWords(searchTerm, arr) {
    let st = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
    return arr.filter(each => each.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(st) === 0);
}

console.log(checkWords('bea', arrayOfObjects));
```